# Comparing every observations from DF1 to every observation in DF2 (DFs have different row lengths)

Tags: r, comparison, tidyverse

i am looking to compare every observation from DF2 to every observation in DF1, to see if it falls within a +/- 1 range.

**Example dataframes:**

```
##DF1:             
     
Obj min max midpoint
23   2   7     4.5 
32   5   6     5.5
24   8   12    10

##DF2: 

Obj min max midpoint
23   2   12    5 
32   5   7     6.0
24   8   16    12
```

All the midpoints in DF2 will be compared to all the midpoints in DF1, and if they are within a range of +/- 1 they are assigned an ID of 1 (makes a new column called "ID") and if they are not they are left blank. After all comparisons have been made, the blank columns should be assigned a value of 0.

**Expectation:**

```
##DF2:

Obj min max midpoint ID
23   2   12    5      1
32   5   7     6.0    1
24   8   14    11     0
```

The transformation of the dataframe should be applied to the Nth dataframe, when it is comparing to the N-1th dataframe. So there will be no transformation applied to the first dataframe as it has nothing to compare to if that makes sense?

Comment: But in last case `11-10=1`, so that `ID` must equal 1. Can you explain?

Comment: Sorry yes you are correct, these are just random numbers i punched in - i have edited it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
DF2$ID <- unlist(lapply(DF2$midpoint, function(x) ifelse(any(abs(x - DF1$midpoint) <= 1),1,0)))
```

Comment: Hello thanks for you're answer, I have a question about this code. Does it compare every observation from DF2$midpoint to DF1$midpoint to see if there are any values that maybe within the +/- 1 range? Sorry if this is a basic question, i am very new to R.

Comment: Correct, **lapply()** applies the function **function(x)** to all elements of **DF2$midpoint** (one each time) and returns a list of results of the function **function(x)**. The parameter **"x"** represents every single element of **DF2$midpoint** that is compared against all elements of **DF1$midpoint**.  **unlist** produces a vector (given a list structure).  **any()** returns a single boolean value (given a collection of boolean values)

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help, if i wanted to apply this function in a loop over a list of dataframes ie. DF1,DF2,DF3...DF121. Would i use a for loop, with i and i-1?

Comment: Yes, a list of dataframes may be accessed like this:

 for(i in seq_along(df_list)){
  df_list[[i]]$ID <- "some statement here"
 }

Comment: for(i in seq_along(list_df)){ list_df$position_tab_[[i]]$ID <- list_df$position_tab_[i]$ID <- unlist(lapply(list_df$position_tab_[i]$midpoint, function(x) ifelse(any(abs(x - list_df$position_tab_[i]$midpoint) <= 1),1,0))) } - i tried this function but it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: To access a list item you need to use double bracket "[[i]]" 
and then acess dataframe field via "$"

for(i in seq_along(list_df)){ 
  list_df[[i]]$position_tab_$ID <- unlist(lapply(list_df[[i]]$position_tab_$midpoint, function(x) ifelse(any(abs(x - the_other_position_tab_$midpoint) <= 1),1,0)))
}

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i am getting this error message: Unknown or uninitialised column: `position_tab_`. I have explained the situation more clearly here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696018/using-for-loop-with-a-list-of-dataframes - as it may be a lot to write in this comment section

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I hope this can help.

```
library(dplyr)
DF2 %>% left_join(DF1 %>% select(c(1,4)) %>% rename(midpoint2=midpoint)) %>% 
  mutate(Index=ifelse(midpoint-midpoint2<1 & midpoint-midpoint2>-1,1,0))
```

Comment: Hello, thankyou for your answer, the issue with this is it assumes each DF has the same row length, however some of my dataframes have varying row lengths (19-25) that is why i needed to be able to compare every observation from DF2 to DF1.

Comment: Please `dput` one of the largest datasets you have to compare. I believe I could give you another solution @Ghandddd

Comment: I have dput, one of the larger dataframes (first one) and the dataframe it would be compared to (second one) from my dataset.

Comment: @Ghandddd In the end you want to compare `DF2` with 25 rows against `DF1` with 24 rows and show all 25 rows, right?

Comment: Hello yes, Essentially i am trying to link objects from one frame to the next - and each DF represents a timeframe for some context. There will be cases where 24 rows may have to be compared with 25 rows with other dataframes too.

Comment: @Ghandddd I have updated the solution, please check and let me know if it worked for your dataframes.

Comment: Hello i have provided a screenshot of what happens: https://gyazo.com/b0a0ab9f2fe475212b8a97fdae8b90c8

Comment: @Ghandddd I believe is because of most of your ids in DF2 are not in the other DF1

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, i tried it between two dataframes that have almost no different between ID's and they are all showing as NA too.

Comment: @Ghandddd Could you `dput` both data frames you mentioned so that I can adjust the code.